# How add text in button fullscreen on Summernote

Tags: javascript, summernote

I just learn about summernote. I try to customize button in toolbar summernote especially button fullscreen. Anybody know how to add text inside button in toolbar fullscreen summernote like this ?

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!